# Apache Flink: multiple task managers in local mode

Tags: apache-flink

In local mode, can I start another task manager?
Although I tried `./taskmanager.sh start`, the number of task manager
at web dashboard didn't change.

The command `./taskmanager.sh start -m localhost:6123` didn't work also.

What should I do?
Is it impossible to start multiple task manager in local mode?

Answer (score 4):

To start another taskmanager, you should run the following inside the flink binary directory:

```
bin/taskmanager.sh start
```

Which should update the number of taskmanagers on the web dashboard and give you an output like this:

```
[INFO] 1 instance(s) of taskmanager are already running on my-localhost.
Starting taskmanager daemon on host my-localhost.
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. There was a typo.
I already tried that command and I saw that output.
But web dashboard didn't change... What's the problem?

Comment: I found that "[INFO] 1 instance(s) of taskmanager are already running on my-localhost." is not represented!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you want to set up a standalone cluster in your
local machine. If that is the case, you could simply edit the
$FLINK_DIST/conf/workers, in which each line represents a TM host. By
default, there is only one TM in localhost. In your case, you could
add a line 'localhost' to it. Then, execute the
$FLINK_DIST/bin/start-cluster.sh, you could see a standalone cluster
with two TM in your local machine.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/deployment/cluster_setup.html#configuring-flink

This option wont work for windows.
https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r7693d0c06ac5ced9a34597c662bcf37b34ef8e799c32cc0edee373b2%40%3Cdev.flink.apache.org%3E